# how to get the cpu's currentClockSpeed, minClockSpeed, maxClockSped

Tags: c#-4.0, wmi

Can i get the cpu's currentClockSpeed, minClockSpeed, maxClockSped.
I have use wmi to do this,but i think the result is not good.
There are no minClockSpeed,and the currentClockSpeed and maxClockSped have the same value,
The currentClockSpeed never changed.My pc's cpu is I5-2300.it support the turbo boost.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Up,i can not get the minClockSpped value.
the currentClockSpeed and the maxclockSpeed have the same value in destop pc.